# Does Processing transparency support removing backgrounds?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, processing

[image]

I have an image with a green background.

I used this function to remove the background.

```
public void removeBackground(PImage img, color c, float thres) {
  colorMode(HSB);
  for(int i = 0; i < img.width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < img.height; j++){
      color cp = img.get(i, j);
      //threshold accounts for compression
      if(abs(hue(cp) - hue(c)) < thres){
        img.set(i, j, color(0,0,0,0));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using these parameters, I attempted to remove the background.

```
PImage FBSprite;
public void settings() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void setup(){
  FBSprite = loadImage("FlappyBirdSprite.jpg");
  FBSprite.resize(50, 0);
  removeBackground(FBSprite, FBSprite.get(0,0), 0.5);
  image(FBSprite, 0, 0);
}

void draw(){
  background(200);
  image(FBSprite, 0, 0);
}
```

The background turns to black instead of transparent.

ARGB result:
[image]

HSB result with 1 alpha:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to love this: change this line

```
colorMode(HSB);
```

for this:

```
colorMode(ARGB);
```

And it should do the trick. What just happened? Unless you *need* to work in HSB at that very specific point, there's no point to it. ARGB is just like RGB but it has an *ALPHA* setting, or transparency if you prefer. Seems like you already were ready to work in ARGB since you set `color(0,0,0,0)` like this, so this may be a a `copy and paste programming` issue. Or maybe you just didn't notice. It happens to me all the time. If that's the first thing, though, try to keep a keen eye for this kind of problem in the future. Most people doesn't talk about other bad design patterns except for spaghetti code which everybody knows, but [cut and paste programming](https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/cut-and-paste-programming) is real and it hurts a lot, especially if you work with some in-house platform with inexistant documentation. Not that it happened to me.

Have fun!

Comment: I tried using the ARGB color mode, but where the border was wasn't totally transparent.

Comment: I think we may be seeing different things. Can you show me a screen cap of your results?

Comment: Added pictures in question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the alpha of the pixels being removed to 0, I set the alpha to 1. The alpha is so small that you can't see the border.